# xcode 6 : tableview in autolayout is working for some devices but not all

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I'm using auto layout to design tableview that uses f**ull margins of the cells and it's working partially.**

**Also tableView separatorStyle is not working too**

```
class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is unclear from your question what is actually not working.

Comment: sorry for that : auto layout is not making the tableview cell image from margin to margin "image fill the whole cell"

Comment: from the screenshots above, you have a constant width constraint of 366px. If you want the image to fill the whole cell in need to pin the image view to left, right, top and bottom edges of the content view and let the width & height adjust themselves based on those constraints.

Comment: thanks it works fine but the text is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First disable the features width any and height any of both the tableview and tableview cell.
click on pin for image view or view you are using as background of cell select all the constraint left,right,top & bottom.You are selecting left,top,bottom in image above you posted. Deselect the height and width you are showing in image above.

If you want to place the text vew or label or etc in right of the table view then select left,right,top and only height. This would definately solve your problem. i am unable to post the image since i didnt have 10 reputation.Hope it will solve your problem.

Now You can also follow these methods:

[iOS - Custom table cell not full width of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633739/ios-custom-table-cell-not-full-width-of-uitableview/30641193#30641193)