# iOS - Custom table cell not full width of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I may be going about this wrong. So I have created a UITableView that essentially has a auto-layout trailing space set to the main view. I am creating a custom cell for this table so I drug on a prototype cell, customized it, and created my class for it. That is all working just fine.

What I can't seem to solve is the custom cell isn't going the full width of the actual table cell so a white background just shows up. If I don't use the custom cell the entire width table cell gets utilized.

I set the constraints for the cell content so that the background image should fill the cell.

What am I doing wrong? Let me know what you need to help solve this.

**ProfileCustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProfileCustomCell : UITableViewCell {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImageView;

@end
```

**ProfileCustomCell.m**

```
#import "ProfileCustomCell.h"

@implementation ProfileCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        self.nameLabel.text = nil;
    }

    return self;

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

**UITableView**

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProfileCustomCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

ProfileCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [child objectForKey:@"first_name"]];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

[image]

Comment: Check the size of background image of cell. I guess it is a problem of auto layout.

Comment: It's something to so with the cell its self. If it was just a background image issue the label would not be where it is. It would be all the way to the right.

Comment: give cell color &identify what's the  cell size

Comment: set a background color on cell's contentView. check whether the imageView has a trailing set to the table's content view ?

Comment: @JoshYork can you share your code.

Comment: @Ashok Londhe I updated it with my code. Currently very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the code please  .

Did you enable the  **Use Auto layout** and **Use Size Classes** as below do that first in both table view and table view cell .and tell me your problem

[image]

> 1)After that select both image and label and do as below

[image]

> 2) Select the image and do below

[image]

> 3) select the label an do the following

[image]

Can you check the link below:

[Table cell content(title) moving left after selecting cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206375/table-cell-contenttitle-moving-left-after-selecting-cell/29210049#29210049)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I originally had a xib file or the cell, but tried doing it in the storyboard, but just didn't work the way I wanted. Going back to the xib file and setting Use Auto layout and Use Size Classes was what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. if u have got problem with auto layout and u have posted it on stack overflow feel free to inform me .. i m fond of solving Autolayout issues

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "filling", auto layout constraints to leading and trailing space to constant 0 and make sure they're not relative to margins.

Answer (score 1):

select your table view cell's connection inspector and check if you haven't connected 
editingAccessoryView by mistake

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those that are still having a similar issue and the above fixes are not working, make sure to set **Estimated Size** of the cell to **None**. This can be done in the **Storyboard Size Inspector**. Was stuck for much to long on this one!