# How can I place two views in a single screen using autolayout Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to create apps which have 2 views (top & bottom).

The top view is scrollable and contains multiple textfields and labels.

The bottom view is non-scrollable but needs to auto adjust to fit into bottom screen like a keyboard when the screen size is changed (I want it to be usable from iPhone 4 to 6 Plus). The bottom view will contain a custom function button to trigger actions and updates in the top view.

I have this working on Android with LinearLayout, but I'm stuck with iOS.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hey did u solve your problem

Comment: there is no image in the link you provided

Comment: did u check my answer

Comment: Yes, I using top scrollview and bottom view with your setting and it works !!! Thanks. I didn't know such way existed. I bought ios book to learn but it touching the surface of ios only.

Comment: If it does then i m hoping you to accept and up-vote my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place table view or scroll view in top which will scroll and  a UIView on bottom. make the height of UIView constant and table view or scroll view which you will use in top will change the height according as the screen size. If you got confused the post the comment.

For table view see this tutorial
[iOS - Custom table cell not full width of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633739/ios-custom-table-cell-not-full-width-of-uitableview/30641193#30641193)

> Step1 : Place table view and view as below . upper part is table view
>   and lower is view

[image]

> Step2: Place the constraints for view as below
>
> AT first

[image]

> At second

[image]

> Step 3: Place the constraints for table view as below

[image]

Try and inform me what u got

Comment: With just a tableview on the screen I can make it to scale when using different screen size but after I add the UIVIEW at the bottom it cannot scale anymore. It looks like it already fixed at the position without scaling or without filling the screen. How am I going to add the View at the bottom and it always dock at the bottom at the same time the top view still scale properly? Any website or guide I can refer to?

Comment: you need to place auto layout features

Answer (score 1):

In your case I will suggest to drag all those buttons into a `UIView`. Then place the buttons with the desired spacing. Select all the buttons and give equal width and equal height constraint. And then give spacing constraints between neighbour buttons or views. And then give constraint for the UIview to the `UIViewcontroller`

Comment: Thanks. Will try to google on how to set the constraint. Hope it is easy to implement.