# How to make the customized UITableViewCell xib width to fit the device width

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am creating a `UITableTableViewCell` from a nib file. I am using width of 320 for the the cell width. I found when I run the app in `iphone 6` simulator, the cell cannot occupy the whole width of the table view.  If I use iphone 5s, the width is just fine. I want to know how to adjust the width of the xib to fit to different iPhone versions.

Comment: do you have your code for setting up the tableView?

Comment: autoLayout and autoResize are made for this purpose.

Comment: can u check my answer

Comment: u can post the design u wants to create on cell view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you enable the  **Use Auto layout** and **Use Size Classes** as below do that first in both table view and table view cell .and tell me your problem

[image]

> 1)After that select both image and label and do as below

[image]

> 2) Select the image and do below

[image]

> 3) select the label an do the following

[image]

Can you check the link below:

[iOS - Custom table cell not full width of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633739/ios-custom-table-cell-not-full-width-of-uitableview/30641193#30641193)

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that the table view is not stretching to match the screen width, and the row is resizing to this incorrect width.

With the table view selected in your Storyboard, ensure all red constraint markers are selected, so that it is able to resize in all directions.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It seems that your table itself doesn't occupy the full width of the screen.
First, set the border to your table view:

```
[[tblList layer]setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
[[tblList layer]setBorderWidth:2.0];
```

Check this first. Then add a comment. 
Actually I set autolayout constraint to my Table view and kept width of my custom `UITableViewCell` to 320. It automatically covers the full width of the screen width.